# 2nd order ODE with bounded and non-periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find (if possible) $f$ such that $$y''(t)+y(t)=f(t)$$ only has bounded and non-periodic solutions in $\Bbb R$.

I tried replacing $f$ with a polynomial, an exponential and a trigonometric function but none of these work. Any hints?

Comment: Take a sum of two sinus functions with incommensurable periods (different from $1$) for $f$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann How do I check if it works and why does it work?

Answer (score 2):

You identified sinusoids as bounded functions, if they occur on the right side you get terms with the same frequency (but different phase and amplitude) in the solution.

To avoid having a periodic solution, you simply need two incommensurable (not rational multiples) frequencies in the solution. For most solutions, that would just require one irrational frequency. But then there will also be solutions that have all coefficients of the homogeneous solution set to zero. To also catch this case, you can just use two such terms on the right side, such as
$$
f(t)=\sin(\sqrt2 t)+\sin(\sqrt3 t).
$$